# How to set text to a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to make a chrome extension for Zendesk that auto capitalizes a certain words as I type.

it was working before but now it doesn't. it's probably because of the update that Zendesk made to their editor that you can no longer update or replace the text of the element inside this div[contenteditable]

[image]

[image]

I tried everything like using innerHTML, textContent, jQuery's text(), etc.. but none of these have worked anymore.
it just keeps on reverting the text to the old one.

I believe there's a function that's been trying to block all of the text alteration being done to the editor.

I tried to remove all of the input event handlers including keyup/keydown, compositionstart and compositionend to the element but it still keeps on reverting my changes

Update:
[image]

Uppdate 2: using execCommand
[image]

Comment: What is inside this div? Expand it. Maybe you are using commands on the wrong DOM-element.

Comment: @MichaelMishin, please check the updated post.

I already tried to use that element as well, it  still didn't work.

Comment: Check if the page has a MutationObserve or DOMSubtreeModified event listeners. Maybe they're tracking changes.

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: @MichaelMishin how do I check that? I don't see it in the event listeners tab

Comment: @wOxxOm. that doesn't work either

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery `val()` method:

```
$('#demo').val('hello');
```

Comment: it still didn't work